# tunnelbear alternative

Tags: vpn

Is there a tunnelbear alternative for ubuntu

I need a software beside web browser to access the internet with a country of my choice "US" and then disable the vpn and enable my default network  on windows there is a tunnelbear but there is not a linux version of this software any ideas

Thank you in advanced

For the solution you can use [this article](http://digitalstudio7.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-install-spotify-in-other.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try Tor.

> Tor is a network of virtual tunnels that allows people and groups to
>   improve their privacy and security on the Internet. It also enables
>   software developers to create new communication tools with built-in
>   privacy features. Tor provides the foundation for a range of
>   applications that allow organizations and individuals to share
>   information over public networks without compromising their privacy.

To install Tor, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

For more information see [Tor](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tor)

<sup>Source:[TorProject](https://www.torproject.org/index.html.en)</sup>